# Assign categorical mapping from one pd.Series to another

Tags: pandas, mapping, categories, categorical-data

I want to apply the mapping from categorical values to codes from one `pd.Series` to another. Consider this snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(['a', 'b']).astype('category')
s2 = pd.Series(['b']).astype('category')

print(s1.cat.codes)
print(s2.cat.codes)

s2.cat.set_categories(s1.cat.categories)
print(s2.cat.codes)
```

The output I expected is:

```
0    0
1    1
dtype: int8
0    0
dtype: int8
0    1
dtype: int8
```

because in `s1` `'b'` is mapped to `1`. But what I get is this:

```
0    0
1    1
dtype: int8
0    0
dtype: int8
0    0
dtype: int8
```

Why? That `set_categories` operation did nothing at all. Seems completely pointless...

But how can I *actually* do this?

(In addition I would need to map values that did not occur in `s1`, such as `'c'` to an error value like `-1`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget assign output back to `s2`:

```
s2 = s2.cat.set_categories(s1.cat.categories)
print (s2)
0    b
dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [a, b]

print(s2.cat.codes)
0    1
dtype: int8
```

Comment: @lotolmencre - In pandas only very few function working inplace, like [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), obviously is necessary `inplace=True` parameter e.g. in [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).